# Could not start a new session. Response code 500. Message: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 105

Tags: selenium, kotlin, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm developing an application that uses selenium.

- OS: macOS with Apple Silicon
- Language: Kotlin
- JDK: Java 18

But it fails.

### Output

```
Starting ChromeDriver 105.0.5195.19 (b9c217c128c16f53d12f9a02933fcfdec1bf49af-refs/branch-heads/5195@{#176}) on port 50362
Only local connections are allowed.
Please see https://chromedriver.chromium.org/security-considerations for suggestions on keeping ChromeDriver safe.
ChromeDriver was started successfully.
org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Could not start a new session. Response code 500. Message: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 105
Current browser version is 104.0.5112.79 with binary path /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome
Build info: version: '4.4.0', revision: 'e5c75ed026a'
System info: host: 'mymac.local', ip: '2400:2200:6f0:7919:347b:3223:3841:9545%en0', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'aarch64', os.version: '12.3', java.version: '18.0.2'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Command: [null, newSession {capabilities=[Capabilities {browserName: chrome, goog:chromeOptions: {args: [], extensions: []}}], desiredCapabilities=Capabilities {browserName: chrome, goog:chromeOptions: {args: [], extensions: []}}}]
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:144)
    ......
```

### build.gradle.kts

```kotlin
dependencies {
    testImplementation(kotlin("test"))
    implementation(compose.desktop.currentOs)

    // Selenium
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java
    implementation("org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-java:4.4.0")
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-chrome-driver
    implementation("org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-chrome-driver:4.4.0")
}
```

### Code

```kotlin
fun launch() {
    System.setProperty(
        "webdriver.chrome.driver",
        "/driver/path/chromedriver"
    );
    ChromeDriver();
}
```

Chrome driver version 105.0.5195.19 is one of the driver I saved at `/driver/path/chromedriver`.
104.0.5112.79 is the version of Chrome I installed on my macOS.

Do I have to use the chromedriver version 104? or is there any way to use one of version 105?

I'm not sure why chrome version on the macOS is needed when I set `webdriver.chrome.driver`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This error message...

```
org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Could not start a new session. Response code 500. Message: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 105
```

...implies that the [ChromeDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59927747/7429447) was unable to initiate/spawn a new *Browsing Context* i.e. [google-chrome](/questions/tagged/google-chrome) session.

Your main issue is the **incompatibility** between the version of the binaries you are using as follows:

- You are using *chromedriver=105.0*
- Release Notes of [*chromedriver=105.0*](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/105.0.5195.19/notes.txt) clearly mentions the following :

> Supports Chrome version 105

- Presumably you are using the latest *chrome=104.0*

So there is a clear mismatch between *chromedriver=105.0* and the *chrome=104.0*

---

### Solution

Ensure that:

- *ChromeDriver* is adjusted to [ChromeDriver v104.0](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=104.0.5112.79/) level.

Also ensure,

- *Chrome Browser* is updated to  current *chrome=104.0* (as per [chromedriver=104.0 release notes](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/104.0.5112.79/notes.txt)).
- *Selenium* is upgraded to  current released [***Version 4.4.0***](https://www.selenium.dev/downloads/).

Comment: I'm confused. So, I have to use the same version of chrome driver file as chrome browser that i installed in the computer right?

Comment: Yeap, that's correct.

Comment: Did your issue get resolved?

Comment: Glad to be able to help you.

Answer (score 1):

You can check you current `Google Chrome` version and if is not `105` you can updated.

In my case was :

```
Version 104.0.5112.102
```

Or another solutions would be downgrade the chrome driver

Answer (score 1):

You can use this :

```
dependencies{
    compile ('org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-java:4.11.0')
    implementation group: 'io.github.bonigarcia', name: 'webdrivermanager', version: '5.5.2'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I also got the same error for Chrome version 116.
Steps I followed:

1. Type the latest version of Chrome driver in the browser
2. It will navigate to https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads
3. Download the latest version. if the latest version is not available then it will give you the path to download Chromedriver latest version for testing like below.

   - If you are using Chrome version 115 or newer, please consult the Chrome for Testing Availability dashboard. This page provides convenient JSON endpoints for specific ChromeDriver version downloading.--
4. After downloading the driver zip file, unzip the file and point to the chromedrive.exe file path.

Answer (score 0):

`Webdrivermanager` version should be updated to the latest

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).